# Why is this command not invoked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, delegatecommand

Here is what I consider the relevant part of the `ListView` in question:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AllSelected}" Command="{Binding ToggleSelectAll}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

The first column is thus a checkbox bound to the `IsSelected` property of the row item, a `PickListPerson`.

The command is declared in the `PersonPickListViewModel` as follows:

```
public DelegateCommand<PersonPickListViewModel> ToggleSelectAll { get; set; } = new DelegateCommand<PersonPickListViewModel>(vm =>
    {
        vm.AllSelected = !vm.AllSelected;
        vm.People.ToList().ForEach(p => p.IsSelected = vm.AllSelected);
    },
    vm => true
);
```

I pass the viewmodel as the command parameter so as to have access to instance properties of the viewmodel in the static context of the command's action delegate.

Yet when I click the header column checkbox, this command is not invoked. Why could that be?

Comment: Missing OnPropertyChanged inside IsSelected and AllSelected? Maybe too obvious to check.

Comment: I have that on `AllSelected', but `IsSelected` belongs to each member of an `ObservableCollection<PickListPerson>`, and I expect that collection to handle change notifications for what it is bound to.

Comment: ObservableCollection raises events automatically but only for adding/removing elements. Still for changing properties inside objects in collection you need OnPropertyChanged notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` at the point you bind the `CommandParamter` is the item from the People collection. I'm guessing this isn't the `PersonPickListViewModel` you're expecting. As whatever this type is can't be cast to `PersonPickListViewModel` the command doesn't get invoked.

**Edit after first comment:** If your `PersonPickListViewModel` is at the root of the window, you can use "DataContext Anchoring" to get to it. Simply add a name to your `Window` (i.e. `x:Name="view"`) and then update your binding to use an `ElementName` source as follows:

`{Binding ElementName=view, Path=DataContext}`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The `PersonPickListViewModel` is the data context for the whole view. How could I specify that as the data context for the header template? I have it specified in the view using `<Window.DataContext><vm:PersonPickListViewModel /></Window.DataContext>`.

Comment: I have expanded the answer to show how this can be achieved.

Comment: Thank you very much. Gaarg, A whole project without using names, and now I need one. I suppose just one is fine.